# How to know when a Service is created?

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes, you can listen for events using `kubectl get events`. This works for other resources, but I would like to know when a Service is created and destroyed.
When I run `kubectl describe my-service` I get `Events:            <none>`.

How can I know when a service was created?

Answer (score 1):

Every api object has a creation timestamp in the metadata section. Though that doesn’t tell when it is edited. For that you might want an audit webhook or something like Brigade.

Answer (score 0):

When a service gets created, you should get the service listed when you run below command

```
Kubectl get svc
```